# Run function in to the wordpress plugin with real Cron job

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I write wordpress plugin .. That plugin have function (Following code)..

I want run function with real Cron job no Wp corn

First I deactivate wordpress cron with follwoing code

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

Then add follwoing code to my host cron

```
wget -q -O - http://kharidsanj.ir/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron >/dev/null 2>&1
```

And Now I want run following function with real Cron job command

```
function import_into_db(){

////My code

}
```

How Can I?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running wp-cron.php on host cron, Use the below code. It worked for me.

```
add_filter('cron_schedules','cliv_cron_add_syncdays');
function cliv_cron_add_syncdays($schedules){
   $schedules['syncdays'] = array(
       'interval' => (86400),
       'display'=> 'Sync Days'
   );
   return $schedules;
}

add_action('init','cliv_create_recurring_schedule');
add_action('cron_action','cron_function');

function cron_function(){
   import_into_db(); // your desired function
}

function cliv_create_recurring_schedule(){
  if(!wp_next_scheduled('cron_action'))
   wp_schedule_event (time(), 'syncdays', 'cron_action');
}
```

Comment: These functions when working witch hit user on site or not, auto working? @Pokhrel Kiran